# How to repeat each value of am index column in R three times for each row

Tags: r

```
tweets1$index <- 1:nrow(tweets1)
tweets2 <- tweets1 %>% pivot_wider(names_from = "X1", values_from = "X2")
tweets2
```

This code creates this data frame:

[image]

I obviously don't want the NA values, and I'd like to have rows 1-3 combined into 1 and so on. Essentially I'd like to group every three rows together. Can I get some advice with this?

Comment: `tweets1$index <- rep(1:(nrow(tweets1)/3), each = 3)`?

Comment: Doesn't work...I think the division part is necessary though

Comment: Without any sample data (as code, eg using the very handy `dput()` function), we will just be guessing what works for your data. Also, "doesn't work" is ambiguous -- did you get an error, or a different result that was wrong, or the same result as before?

Comment: obothehobo, JonSpring requested that you provide sample data using `dput`, and since neither of our answers apparently resolves your issue, I suggest you give more thought to giving us sample data. See https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269, [mcve], and https://stackoverflow.com/tags/r/info for how to update your question to make it clearer, both from an input and an expect-output perspective.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, this is my first post here so not too familiar. Thanks JonSpring for the help, that code ended up working once I deleted the last row of the data frame which included a "cutoff" tweet. After doing that, the number of rows was divisible by three so your suggested code worked. Thank you!

Comment: I made the assumption from the question that the OP had complete data with three entries per group and nothing extra. I edited my answer to show to approaches that could manage if that's not the case. 1) integer division would be robust to the last group having under 3 entries 2) counting cumulative `a` entries would be robust to groups missing a `b` or `c`.

Answer (score 0):

Stemming off of:

- *"don't want the NA values"*, and
- *"rows 1-3 combined into 1 and so on"*

Perhaps this will work:

```r
dat <- data.frame(id=1:6, T=c("2009-06-11",NA,NA,"2009-06-11",NA,NA), U=c(NA,"https://www1",NA,NA,"https://www2",NA),W=c(NA,NA,"post1",NA,NA,"post2"))
dat
#   id          T            U     W
# 1  1 2009-06-11         <NA>  <NA>
# 2  2       <NA> https://www1  <NA>
# 3  3       <NA>         <NA> post1
# 4  4 2009-06-11         <NA>  <NA>
# 5  5       <NA> https://www2  <NA>
# 6  6       <NA>         <NA> post2

by(
  dat, cumsum(!is.na(dat$T)),
  function(Z) data.frame(lapply(Z[-1], function(x) paste(na.omit(x), collapse=";")[1]))
) |>
  do.call(rbind, args = _)
#            T            U     W
# 1 2009-06-11 https://www1 post1
# 2 2009-06-11 https://www2 post2
```

(`|>` and `_` requires R >= 4.2.0, this can be made to work with older R without difficulty.)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your original dataframe looks like this:

```
  X1    X2
1  a  blip
2  b  blap
3  c blorp
4  a  slip
5  b  slop
6  c slorp
```

EDIT: Old approach required *3n* rows.

In case the last group is partial or unrelated to the other data, we can use integer division to assign groups of three, with the last group potentially having between 1-3 members.

```
df$index = (1:nrow(df)-1) %/% 3
```

In case other groups might be partial, but the data is in order and every group has a unique `a`, we could count a new group as being the appearance of non-NA data in `a`:

```
df$index = cumsum(!is.na(df$a))
```

Producing

```
  X1    X2 index
1  a  blip     1
2  b  blap     1
3  c blorp     1
4  a  slip     2
5  b  slop     2
6  c slorp     2
```

So that we can do:

```
df %>% pivot_wider(names_from = "X1", values_from = "X2")


# A tibble: 2 × 4
  index a     b     c    
  <int> <chr> <chr> <chr>
1     1 blip  blap  blorp
2     2 slip  slop  slorp
```

Comment: (But the fact that this "doesn't work" suggests there is more to your question/data than what I can divine from your screenshot.)

Comment: Edited to deal with potentially incomplete data for the last group, or incomplete data in other groups provided that all groups have an `a` value.